# get number of affected rows from Teradata query history

Tags: teradata

Is there a way to find out how many rows were affected by e.g. a MERGE statement that was executed a few days ago on a Teradata Database?
We know of the existance of things like DBC.QryLogSQLV and pdcrinfo.dbqlsqltbl but this only shows the statements that were executed (to my knowledge); not the results.

Thank you.

Comment: You get details in `dbc.QryLogV.StmtDMLRowCount` (TD16.20) or `QryLogStepsV`, columns `RowCount,RowCount2,RowCount3` (if collected)

Comment: awesome, many thanks

Comment: If you're running it inside SQL*Assistant, you will see the number of rows affected in the History | Rows column as well.

Comment: hi, yes - however we need to figure out where and when in our ETL batch process, some data was potentially deleted. So it is a system user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
SELECT T.NumResultRows, T.*, 
FROM DBC.QRYLOG AS T
WHERE ClientID = '<user_name>'
    AND QueryText LIKE '%<QueryText>%' -- QueryID will be better if you know it
ORDER BY StartTime DESC;
```

Please keep in mind that QueryText column contains the first 200 characters of the query.
You can read more here:
https://docs.teradata.com/reader/wada1XMYPkZVTqPKz2CNaw/yN7rZjxzOUm2BVksZyziVg